# Atiyah-Macdonald 11.20 and 11.21

Tags: commutative-algebra

[image]

Here, shouldn't the $x_i$s map to $x_i + \mathfrak{q}^2$, rather than to $x_i +\mathfrak{q}$? If not, then everything would be mapped to degree $1$ elements.

This is another one:
[image]

Here, where is the fact that $k$ maps isomorphically onto $A/\mathfrak{m}$ used?
If $f_s$ has coefficients in $\mathfrak{m}$, they can't be invertible and hence can only be zero as all the other elements of $k$ are invertible($k$ is a field).

Comment: The error you found in the proof of Proposition 11.20 is mentioned at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42241/errata-for-atiyah-macdonald (with the same correction).

Comment: I think you're right about Corollary 11.21. Atiyah and Macdonald just didn't think of the invertibility argument, it seems.

Comment: I think you meant 'eveything would be mapped to degree 0 elements' instead of 'degree 1'.